# comparing two ExtendedProperty's

Tags: c#

I am working in C#, so I have a define list of ExtendedProperty's, then I pull another list of ExtendedProperty's.

So ExtendedProperty myprop & ExtendedProperty pulledList

Now I would like to compare both ExtendedProperty's.  However both extendedProperty list are not in the same order.  How could i itterate though both list and compare the fields to see if they match.

I was thinking like the defind list myProps, and check the first prop against all from the pulled list and see if they match, then move on to the second one and compare against the pulled list, and so on and so forth.

I think i have the logic down, but I don't know how to go about coding this.

Anyhelp would be appreciated on how to code this would be apprecaited.

Comment: What is `ExtendedProperty`?  How is it defined?

Comment: I should have said List.  It's a list.

Comment: But a "List" of what?  What type of class? What are its properties?  We can't help you determine how to check for matches without knowing how it's defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use LINQ to compare the two List's. LINQ has several methods that can be a of great help for this. You can use the Except method or the Intersect method of LINQ, depending on what your need is. You can use Intersect to create one List that contains the common values shared by both Lists. You can use Except to create a List that contains the values from List A that are are not also in List B. This is a great site for some examples:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b